# Invalid session using SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, session

I'm using SOAP API to read some info from my org. The call flow is typical and work well for my other orgs: login (using old style username/password), set session id and server url then call describe. Unfortunately, describe call fails with "Invalid session Id" error (login was successfull). The user credentials are used only for this integration, user has System Admin profile, IP address is whitelisted (but I'm using security token also). The org has many Connect Apps running using different user credentials. 
My question: what can cause this issue? Are there any Salesforce settings which can potentially prevent using SOAP API while allowing Connected Apps?

Comment: Do other tools that utilize the SOAP API have the same issue for the same user?

Comment: Does the server URL that comes back in the login response include a custom domain? I'd take the session Id and server URL over to something like SOAP UI to see if the calls can be made from there.

Comment: "Do other tools that utilize the SOAP API have the same issue for the same user?". This is the only tools utilizes SOAP API.

Comment: "Does the server URL that comes back in the login response include a custom domain?". No, it's standard euX.salesforce.com

Comment: By other tools I meant try a 3rd parties tool that is known to use the SOAP API to do the authentication. This could help identify if it is something specific with your code or something with the Salesforce session/user configuration.
For example, I make the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) (which is released for free via my current employer). It can use the SOAP based login call for a UN and password then do the describe calls. Might be work trying to help isolate the problem.

Comment: If the IP is whitelisted by profile by "Login IP Ranges" then you will NOT use the security token and must be coming from one of the IP's. Try removing the security token. If that does not work then generate a new security token as you may have the wrong one.

Comment: @Eric, tried with and without security token, the result is the same.